# How to disable modal-ok slot of b-modal in vue bootstrap?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I have used `modal-ok` slot available in [b-modal slots](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#comp-ref-b-modal-slots) to render the OK button of b-modal. I want to conditionally disable the OK button. I have tried 2 methods with no luck. Any suggestion is welcome on how to disable the OK button rendered using the slot.

1. Disabled prop

   ```
    <div
       slot="modal-ok"
       :disabled="true"
       @click.stop="uploadFile(item.id)"
     >
       Upload
     </div>
   ```
2. ok-disabled prop of b-modal

   ```
     <div
       slot="modal-ok"
       :ok-disabled="true"
       @click.stop="uploadFile(item.id)"
     >
       Upload
     </div>
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

model-ok scope can't modify button itself, it just change button content

You need to use `modal-footer` scope instead and declare buttons manually there.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `ok-disabled` prop on `<b-modal>`, to conditionally enable/disable the `ok` button.

```html
<b-modal :ok-disabled="true">
  <!-- Content -->
</b-modal>
```

For more information check out [this](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#disabling-built-in-footer-buttons) section of the documentation.

Comment: I haven't used the default ok-button of the b-modal. I have used modal-ok slot to render a custom ok-button. This answer is not relevant to that.

Comment: I'd argue that it is. Since the slot you're using only controls the content of the `ok` button. So this will still disable the button. What i don't quite understand though is *why* you're doing what you're doing. At least based on your code in the question, nothing there requires you to use the slot and could be done through the normal props.

Answer (score 9):

Just add hide-footer if you want to get rid of the buttons

```
<b-modal hide-footer>
  <!-- Content -->
</b-modal>
```